# Spring init methods

Tags: java, spring

I'm learning spring and I got confused in init, destroy method and constructor part

This is `spring-config.xml`

```
   <bean id="msgBean" class="com.example1.MessagesBean" init-method="start">

    </bean>  

    <bean name="carBean" class="com.example2.Car" init-method="initEngine">
        <constructor-arg ref="engineBean" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="engineBean" class="com.example2.Engine" />
```

This is `Car.java`

```
public class Car {

    private Engine engine;

    public Car(Engine engine){
        System.out.println("Inside Car constructor");
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public void startCarEngine(){
        engine.startEngine();
    }

    private void initEngine(){
        System.out.println("heating up engine");
    }
}
```

This is `Engine.java`

```
public class Engine {

    public Engine(){
        System.out.println("Inside Engine constructor");
    }

    public void startEngine(){
        System.out.println("Engine is starting...");
    }
}
```

This is `MessageBean.java`

```
public class MessagesBean {

    private static final String HELLO_WORLD = "Hello World";

    public MessagesBean(){
        System.out.println("Printing " + HELLO_WORLD);
    }


    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Step 2.Bean is starting");
    }   

}
```

This is my `Main class`

```
    AbstractApplicationContext abstractAppContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
    MessagesBean msgBean2 = abstractAppContext.getBean("msgBean", MessagesBean.class);
```

This is my `output`

```
    Printing Hello World
    Step 2.Bean is starting
    Inside Engine constructor
    Inside Car constructor
    heating up engine
```

My question is I called only `MessageBean` in my main class and it's supposed to call only `MessageBean Constructor` and `init` method but why two other beans constructors and init method are called or did I do something wrong? What if I have different init, destroy methods for different beans and I only want to initialize/call specific bean(s) constructors and init methods ?

Comment: If you mark it for lazy init, it will create beans lazily. By default it is eager.

Comment: read thishttp://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by default spring beans gets eagerly initialized, if you want them to initialize lazily add this property in bean definition

```
lazy-init="true"
```